# Reduce gcc memory usage

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, gcc, build

Currently I have to build a quite large project on a very limited hardware (a core i5 which have only 2gb RAM). When run make with 4 thread gcc crashed due to each thread eats up to 40% RAM. 
I googled a bit and found this [link](http://jkroon.blogs.uls.co.za/it/scriptingprogramming/preventing-gcc-from-trashing-the-system). A few people feedback it works.However, not me.

Here is how I did.

```
/usr/bin/qmake-qt4 -r -spec linux-g++ $DEBUG_FLAGS -o Makefile "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS +=  --param ggc-min-expand=10 --param ggc-min-heapsize=8192"  /home/build-srv/LargeProject/largeProject.pro
```

make output does have the flag:

```
g++ -c -pipe --param ggc-min-expand=10 --param ggc-min-heapsize=8192 -std=c++11 -std=c++11 -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -DBASE_LIBRARY -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++  -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtDeclarative...
```

But the ram usage still the same. The only way is reduce to single thread build, which is awfully slow.

What did I do wrong? Are there any better solution for this.

**Update**:

- Yes, the hardware department "upgrade"  the RAM capacity to 4GB and now it's responsive when building the project.(Actually a stick broke so they need to wait the replacement). But I'm curious that in a limited resource system like a VPS how can we handle that? (Except reduce the build threads?)
- I will search for the file that eat up a alot of RAM when compiling/linking. I dont remember the name due to that ain't my modules.
- The build server had 2GB of swap space.

Comment: Do you have large source files? Many templates? Many included header files? If you preprocess the source files, how large are they (typically)?

Comment: Tomorrow morning go and buy 4 more GB.

Comment: CPU cycles, and RAM, cannot be created out of thin air. If you do not have enough RAM for four concurrent compiles, then dial it down to 3 or 2, or however many can fit into RAM. gcc does not have a reputation for using up a bunch of RAM for no good reason. Artificially reducing the RAM it can use means that it will take longer to compile the same source, so, in the end, you may end up succeeding in running four concurrent compile cycles, but if you were to, say, let gcc use all the RAM it wants, and compile two at a time, it'll probably take the same amount of time to do it.

Comment: Do you have at least some swap space configured? It would avoid wasting some part of the RAM on unused stuff.

Comment: Sooo sorry for the late reply, I updated the the question to provide the information you need.

Answer (score 10):

Tell your employer that the tools they provide for your job are inadequate. That's a bit of a joke of a system for what you're doing, and I assume it's provided by the employer. You need more RAM, no doubt about it. It should be simple enough to extend the RAM, there are no i5 motherboards that only take 2G as a maximum.

Otherwise - yes, you will need to limit the number of threads, e.g. use `make -j2` or even `make -j1.` Modern compilers need lots of RAM not because they are wasteful, but because they hold the entire translation unit's worth of information in memory at once to provide global optimizations. Link-time code generation will need even more memory as it holds the information about the entire application.

Comment: I'm having an issue where gcc uses more than 8GB of RAM :(. I don't know what to do, 2 files cause this.